# grunt-ngdocs: styles file not included to demo code

Tags: ngdoc, grunt-ngdocs

I am using [`grunt-ngdocs`](https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs) to document my Angular project. But the demo Plunker code (generated automatically) doesn't include the CSS file.

My configuration in `Gruntfile.js` includes:

```
...
scripts: [
    'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js'
],
styles: [
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.0.7/semantic.css'
]
...
```

In my JS src file:

```
@example
    <example module="sui.checkbox">
        <file name="index.html">
        ...
        </file>
    <example>
```

On the API page, the JS and CSS files are loaded correctly. However the displayed `demo` source code doesn't include the CSS file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="sui.checkbox">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- semantic.css should be imported here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

On my API page, the demo works well. But linking to Plunker doesn't produce desired result, because the CSS including line is not there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a temp solution. Add the following line **inside** the javascript files `@example` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.0.7/semantic.css">
```

Comment: this solution does not worked for me. It freezes the browser when the css getting loaded. I tried with mozilla and chrome and both are freezing